# Creating a copy of a Django JSONField value

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a copy of a JSON model field using `.copy()` however any changes I make to the copy are still being reflected in the database which I don't want. I could iterate the model field and create a new dictionary but I figured theres a more pythonic way..

Models.py

```
Class User(models.model):
  settings = models.JSONField(default=dict(color = "Yellow",  shape = "Square"))
```

views.py

```
... 
user = User.objects.get(id=1)
settings = user.settings
settings_copy = user.settings.copy()
#settings model field is being changed here despite being a copy
settings_copy['color'] = Blue 
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically use `dict.copy` which is a **shallow** copy of the dictionary, i.e. the internal objects refer to the same instance referred by the original. Try using `copy.deepcopy` instead:

```
import copy

... 
user = User.objects.get(id=1)
settings = user.settings
settings_copy = copy.deepcopy(settings)
settings_copy['color'] = Blue 
...
```